# web login with facebook using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to login with facebook from my localhost using php.
This is config.php

```
<?php
include_once("inc/facebook.php"); //include facebook SDK

$appId = '50*****'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret = 'c79aa****'; // Facebook App Secret
$homeurl = '192.168.1.12:8080/facebook_login';  //return to home
$fbPermissions = '';  //Required facebook permissions


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => $appId,
'secret' => $appSecret

));
$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
 ?>
```

It is giving this error

"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Please give me solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! Please read [ask] and share a [mcve]!

Comment: that question is subject of countless threads on stackoverflow already, please do some research before asking.